# action update only last object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

From last two days i try expect whats going on in my app. This is my problem:

My model:

```
class User
has_many :orders
---
class Order
belongs_to :user
has_and_belongs_to_many :contributors, class_name: 'User'
```

Situation: 
User can create order, next for this order can add contributors(other users) with
     `<%= collection_check_boxes(:order, :contributor_ids, @prac, :id, :to_s) %>`

After that in my custom action in OrdersController i have something like this:

```
@order.contributors.each do |u|
u.orders << @order
end
```

Here i want add this order to list of contributors(users) orders. Unfortunately this work only for last contributor(user). Below log from my console:

```
    Started PATCH "/orders/282/zatwierdz" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-01 08:48:59 +0200

Processing by OrdersController#zatwierdz as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"hxWUnazKLoS9t8bVmOAMeIxdo/KYuO33bUeuQZYgeV
k=", "id"=>"282"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 32  OR
DER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles"  WHERE "roles"."id" = ? LIMI
T 1  [["id", 4]]
  Order Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders"  WHERE "orders"."id" = ?
 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 282]]
  OrderItem Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "order_items"  WHERE "order_it
ems"."order_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 282]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "orders" SET "status" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "orders"
."id" = 282  [["status", 1], ["updated_at", "2014-07-01 06:48:59.486472"]]
   (62.5ms)  commit transaction
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "orders_users" ON
"users"."id" = "orders_users"."user_id" WHERE "orders_users"."order_id" = ?  [["
order_id", 282]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "orders" SET "updated_at" = ?, "user_id" = ? WHERE "orders
"."id" = 282  [["updated_at", "2014-07-01 06:48:59.564595"], ["user_id", 33]]
   (78.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "orders" SET "updated_at" = ?, "user_id" = ? WHERE "orders
"."id" = 282  [["updated_at", "2014-07-01 06:48:59.642719"], ["user_id", 35]]
   (78.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "orders" SET "updated_at" = ?, "user_id" = ? WHERE "orders
"."id" = 282  [["updated_at", "2014-07-01 06:48:59.720842"], ["user_id", 36]]
   (109.4ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "orders" SET "updated_at" = ?, "user_id" = ? WHERE "orders
"."id" = 282  [["updated_at", "2014-07-01 06:48:59.830215"], ["user_id", 37]]
   (78.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/orders/282
Completed 302 Found in 437ms (ActiveRecord: 406.2ms)
```

I try use this action with callbacks and from model methods but nothing happened. Maybe better for this aprouch is to use other associations? Anny sugestions welcome.
Thx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing:

```
@order.contributors.each do |u|
  u.orders << @order
end
```

You are adding your order to the user.orders relationship, which you define as a many (Order) to one (User). The "has_many" orders on the User class is just the other side of the "belongs_to" user on the Order class. So yes, as per your model, an Order has one and only one user.

Now, if you want to be able to navigate your has_and_belongs_to_many relation from the User side, you need to [define it there too](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

Comment: It's obvious... now :)
Thanks for help.